# C# casting an object within lambda

Tags: c#, dynamic, lambda, lazy-evaluation, func

I am currently trying to set a field which I need in business logic which in this case is Lazy.
(yes not the property, it is necessary to set the field)
I get the error that Lazy can not be converted to Lazy
as you can see:

> Object of type
>   'BusinessLogic.Lazy`1[System.Object]'
>   cannot be converted to type
>   'BusinessLogic.Lazy`1[BusinessLogic.ArtikelBLL]

I use this line to get a dynamic repository.

```
dynamic repository = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(GenericRepository<>).MakeGenericType(typeArgs));
```

Then I try to set the value of the field but it fails:

```
fInfo.SetValue(obj, Lazy.From(() => repository.GetDataById(id)));
```

I have tried to solve it many different ways.
Somehow I have to cast `repository.GetDataById(id)` to the Entity it is looking for, which in this case is ArtikelBLL (which i can get through `pInfo.PropertyType`).
But by doing `(ArtikelBLL)repository.GetDataById(id)` it will not remain object orientated.
Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: Some info you could provide to better answers: Why would it no longer be object-oriented if you wrote `(ArtikelBLL)repository.GetDataById(id)`? What's the type of the field? What's the relation between `GenericBLL` and `ArtikelBLL` (I guess one is the latter is a subclass of the former, but you could clarify)? What type is the object returned by GetDataById?

Comment: ArtikelBLL is indeed a subclass of GenericBLL. Because the repository is dynamic GetDataById should return the Entity(in this case ArtikelBLL) that is T in the Repository<T>. It is not object orientated because it is in a forloop and the repository would need to return other subclasses as well (for instance i have LieferantenBLL), which would return errors if i casted it to ArtikelBLL. The type of the field is Lazy<ArtikelBLL>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to just use a cast inside the lambda:

```
fInfo.SetValue(obj, new Lazy<GenericBLL>(
    () => (ArtikelBLL) repository.GetDataById(id)));
```

After all, that's the type the `Lazy<T>` wants.

EDIT: If you're trying to do this dynamically, I suggest you write a generic method like this:

```
public Lazy<T> CreateLazyDataFetcher<T>(dynamic repository)
{
    return new Lazy<T>(() => (T) repository.GetDataById(id));
}
```

Then call that method with reflection. (Using `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(...).Invoke(...)`)

Comment: I get the following error:
Object of type 'BusinessLogic.Lazy`1[BusinessLogic.GenericBLL]' cannot be converted to type 'BusinessLogic.Lazy`1[BusinessLogic.ArtikelBLL]'.

Comment: You are trying to cast two types that aren't compatible with each other. One is a Lazy<ArtikelBLL>, the other is Lazy<GenericBLL>.

Comment: I edited my question: The new Lazy<GenericBLL>() was wrong so I use fInfo.SetValue(obj, Lazy.From(() => repository.GetDataById(id))); this will ask for a Lazy<ArtikelBLL>, but how do I cast repository.GetDataById(id) to the type of pInfo.PropertyType within the Lazy?

Comment: @vcsjones: The question was edited since I wrote my answer :(

Comment: @user653830: If you're using `Lazy.From`, that's going to need the relevant type anyway for type inference. I'll edit my answer.